# Simple Cache Implementation in C

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, pointers, caching

Why someone might implement a cache as

```
void DoSomethingWith(CGColorRef color)
{
    static CGColorRef cachedColor = NULL;
    static int cachedColorID = 0;

    if (color == cachedColor && color->colorID == cachedColorID)
    {
        UseCachedColorTransformations();
    }
    else
    {
        cachedColor = color;
        cachedColorID = color->colorID;
        CalculateColorTransformations();
        CacheColorTransformations();
    }
    ...
}
```

instead of merely comparing colorIDs?

```
void DoSomethingWith(CGColorRef color)
{
    static CGColorRef cachedColor = NULL;
    static int cachedColorID = 0;

    if (color->colorID == cachedColorID)
    {
        UseCachedColorTransformations();
    }
    else
    {
        cachedColor = color;
        cachedColorID = color->colorID;
        CalculateColorTransformations();
        CacheColorTransformations();
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that color->colorID value is an incremental value that starts from 1 and assigned thread safely (InterlockedIncrement from a Global counter) to colors at creation.

Global counter is not decremented when some color deleted and colors are not moved or copied in memory. So, each color has a unique colorID value, a colorID could be used by only one color at an address. Some color could be deleted and another one could be created at the same address so there will be a color with a different colorID at the same address which we could use to determine if its the same color or another one recreated at that address.

Thus, its not necessary to compare references, **its enough to compare colorIDs**; they are unique and identify exactly one color at it's unique address.

Comment: Because the person that wrote this thought about it differently than you do? Perhaps they were right? Perhaps you are wrong? Perhaps its the other way around? Rule #1: Never assume you work with idiots. I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for with this question, but your closing sentence seems to suggest you're looking for confirmation; not an answer.

Comment: I don't assume that i am right and i don't expect that they overlooked something. So, i am looking for their disparate thought.

Comment: Ah.. Well, not being them i can only speculate, but it would appear they considered the possibility that someone may pass a colorID that is *not* in lock-step with the cached ref, but pass the same ref modified with the new id, and thereby trip a cache reset. Not a lot of code here, but that would seem one reasonable possibility. It would easily be squelched if the `colorID` was `const` and thus not mutable after creation of the ref. Your logic seems sound, however. especially if the restrictions you state are really there.

Comment: Another reason would be to skip colorID comparisons when refs are not equal but in that case transformations will require a lot of computations so it would be a premature optimization. Also, comparing refs is a waste of time when colorIDs are already equal.

Comment: I rethought about your logic and could not understand it. Only color is passed to the function and colorID is obtained from it... My proposal is that if another color created at another address with the same colorID as the cached one would require comparing both ref and ids. I don't have the whole code so i am not sure that colorID is actually not modified by some code.